# Counting number of strings in hash table

Tags: c, memory-management, hash, hashtable

So, I am trying to count the number of strings present in my hash table. For some reason, this function always returns 0. I have tried re-writing it a couple of times in slightly different ways to find an error in the logic, but, as far as I know, this function should output the number of entries in the table. I would really appreciate some help, as this has become very frustrating! Thanks!

```
/* htbl_n_entries : htbl* -> unsigned int */
/* return the number of entries in all buckets */
unsigned int htbl_n_entries(htbl *t){
    int i;
    int nbucks = t->n_buckets;
    sll**bucks= t->buckets;
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nbucks; ++i)
    {
        while(bucks[i] != NULL){
        sum++;
        bucks[i] = bucks[i]->next;
    }
}
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `nbucks` > 0 ?

Comment: Not in this function function (though perhaps I should), but in the situation in which the function is called, there are 10 buckets.

Comment: I would make sure that the object you are passing via `t` works properly first. Maybe add a few simple `cout`'s just to see what its properties are. then worry about your function.

Comment: Why does your counting function modify the hash table?

Comment: I wasn't sure of any other way to progress through the string linked list without modifying "bucks." It shouldn't change the tree, though, as I created a new variable.

Comment: Have you considered adding some `printf` statements (e.g. `Counting bucket 1/10...`) to see what the code does at runtime? Nothing seems wrong, so I assume the the issue may be `n_buckets` is wrong or even the hash table structure itself is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The while in your code will set to NULL each `bucks[i].` Try:

```
sll**bucks= t->buckets;
unsigned int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < nbucks; ++i)
{
        sll*bucks_= bucks[i];
    while(bucks_ != NULL){
    sum++;
    bucks_ = bucks_->next;
}
}
```

This is just one error, but do not explain why return 0. It correctly count the first time, but any other time will be 0. My gess is that you have simmilar error in other functions and at this point your table is allready broken.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis :  it change the table, NULL-ing each beggening-bucks

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as soon as I typed the comment, but couldn't delete from iPhone.

Comment: @Alex Nichols  by your comment it is possible you have the table allready changed in other simmilar function, just trying to iterate the lists